# Loop PHP forms a chosen number of time from drop box

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<div id="form1" />
   <form name="choice">
       <table> 
           <tr>
               <td>
                   Number of new types you want to add
               </td>
               <td>
                   <select name="<?php echo $num; ?>">
                    <option value="1" selected>1 row</option>
                    <option value="2">2 rows</option>
                    <option value="3">3 rows</option>
                    <option value="4">4 rows</option>
                    <option value="5">5 rows</option>                        
                    </select>
                   <div class='inputs'></div>
               </td>
           </tr>

       </table>
   </form>            

    <form name="myForm" action="addAccessories.php"  method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
        <table border="1">
            <tr> 
                <th>Barcode<em>*</em></th>
                <th>Description<em>*</em></th>
                <th>Minimum required stock<em>*</em></th>
                <th>Current stock</th>
            </tr>    
            <?php
                echo $num;
            ?>
            <tr>                    
                <td><input type="text"  name="bar_code/></td>

                <div class="ui-widget">                                
                <td><input name="description/></td>                
                </div>

                <td><input type="text"  name="minimum_required_stock" /></td>
                <td><input type="text"  name="num_stock" value="0"></td>

            <tr>
                <td> </td> 
                <td> <button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Add   accessories</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Hello guys,
In this code I have 2 form, 1 is the drop box has 5 options and a form for text input. 
In theory, if I choose option value="3", the text form will be loop 3 times and get 3 set of text inputs. However, I haven't succeeded in doing this by far. And also, how can I access these 3 sets of data in addAccessories.php file?

I appreciate any opinion on this topic.
Thank you very much.

Comment: It seems really weird that $num is a name attribute and can also appear between the rows of a table.  What is $num?

Comment: Maybe you could consider reformatting your code to contain the bare minimum that we need to help you? This way we have to read a lot of code before we even see what is going on. Also what are you trying to do? Could you explain more clearly? Maybe step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, it sounds like you want to have code such that when the selection in form choice changes, you change the number of rows in form myform.  This is not possible from php because it will be a runtime change on the client machine.  You can write this in javascript.  You will need code called from form choice that adjusts the DOM in form myform.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a pure PHP solution and rebuild the page - but that's clunky and slow (which, might be fine for a pet project). Normally we'd use Javascript with AJAX to accomplish something like this.